# If the symmetric part of a matrix is PSD then the matrix is PSD

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, positive-semidefinite

My professor said this during my linear algebra class. But I am not sure how to prove this.

If A is any matrix, then it can be decomposed into a symmetric and anti-symmetric part like below-

$$
A = \frac{A+A^T}{2} + \frac{A-A^T}{2}
$$

Then for any $x\neq 0$, the statement claims that if the following holds,

$$
x^T (\frac{A+A^T}{2}) x \geq 0
$$

then, $x^T A x \geq 0$. I am not sure why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Distributing, we have
$$
x^T (\frac{A+A^T}{2}) x =\frac{1}{2}\left(x^T A x + x^T A^Tx\right)
$$
Now consider $x^T A^Tx$. Since it's a scalar, we must have
$$
x^T A^Tx = \left(x^T A^Tx\right)^T = x^TAx
$$
so
$$
x^T (\frac{A+A^T}{2}) x =\frac{1}{2}\left(x^T A x + x^T A x\right) = x^T A x.
$$